# React Redux is not updating component state in real time

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have one component `ImageGallery`, in there I want to load more images after pressing `Load More` button. And, `loadMore()` function updates a react-redux `globalState.js` initialState value `limit`. But, When I am pressing `Load More` button I have to press 2 times for the first time to get the first `16` images. After that it's updating value as expected. But, first time I have to press `2` times. But, I want, it will work on first time  click and get `16` items and so on.

`globalState.js`:

```js
export const globalState = createSlice({
  name: "global",
  initialState: {
  limit: 8
  }
  reducers: {
    // imageGallery
    incrementLimitGallery: (state) => {
      state.limit += 8;
    },
   },
});
```

Component `ImageGallery.jsx`:

```js
let API = "https://www.example.com/images/";

export default function ImageGallery() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const limit = useSelector((state) => state.global.limit);
  const [images, setimages] = useState(null);

  async function fetchImages() {
    const response = await axios.get(API + limit);
    if ("error" in response.data) {
      setimages(null);
    } else {
      setimages(response.data);
    }
  }

  const loadMore = async () => {
    dispatch(incrementLimitGallery());
    await fetchImages();
  };

  return (
    <>
     //implementation of image gallery, long code so hide it
      <div>{images ? (imgaes.map(image => (.......))): null}</div>

      <div>
        <button onClick={() => loadMore()}>Load More</button>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: what happened here in loadmore() event you are not calling fetchimages() method so that it's happend

Comment: I have updated. `fetchImages()` is in real code. And, everything is totally fine, I just  need to click `Load More` button 2 times for the first update  of`16` images. That's actually the problem.

Comment: is it working now?

Comment: No. In my code I have already `fetchImages()` called in `loadMore()` I forget to add in here. I just need a solution for why I need to click button 2 times for the first update of 16?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code will not work because it runs asynchronously so when you call `fetchImages` state hasn't been updated yet.

What I would propose is to use `fetchImages` inside a `useEffect` function which is dependent on `limit`.

`loadMore` on the other hand will trigger the redux state update and especially the `limit` update so then `useEffect` will run again.

```
  const loadMore = () => {
    dispatch(incrementLimitGallery());
  };
```

and something like this

```
useEffect(() => {
  fetchImages();
}, [limit]);
```

Comment: It's working perfectly. But, in my code is `limit` updating after `fetch`?

Comment: i dont think you will find a senario where `limit` gets updated before `fetch`. if you make 50 reloads you may face 1 senario, which i even doubt about that. So in order not to play with possibilities you let react lifecycle methods do the job :)

Comment: Okay. One thing, when I update `limit` or any `state` value, is it updating its value in real time, with all shared components?

Comment: no, all are asynchronous, but since they are in millis, you think that it is in real time, but when you place a `console.log` right after the setter method, you will see that the old value is displayed.

Answer (score 1):

You can `modify` your loadmore function like this :

```
const loadMore = async () => {
    dispatch(incrementLimitGallery())
    .then(()=>{
        await fetchImages();
     });
  };
```

As the problem is, your `redux` state is `not` updated when you are `fetching` the `images` after the `distpatch` function(as dispatch is an `async` task). So you can run `fetchImages` function when the `redux` state is `updated`. Use `.then` method to implement the `logic`, as shown above.